# How to use groupby() to group data that spans many years by the day and month?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have a dataset that spans many years. There are multiple data entries for every day of the year. I will like to groupby the day of the year. i.e day-month, then use agg() to find the max value so that I am left with 365 rows.

My method is to create a new column that takes the index which is in the format yyyy-mm-dd and strip the year such that it becomes mm-dd and use groupby on this column. I know that will work.

But I have converted the index into a datetime object using pd.to_datetime(df.index). I want to learn how to work with the datetime index and I believe there is a way to use the datetime object index to do this in a clean way. Please show me a clean way :). Thank you

```
df.groupby([df.index.month, df.index.day]).agg({"Data_Value":np.max})
```

The output is multi index and I do not want it that way

Answer (score 0):

Use `strftime` on the date information so you get "mm-dd" values, then aggregate by that:

```
df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%m-%d')).agg({"Data_Value":np.max})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is a time series, consider [**`Data frame.resample`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```py
df[["Data_Value"]].resample("1D").max()
```